Paddle OCR not able to extract single digits from image
I am doing an image OCR using Paddle OCR. Below is the sample code I am using:
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR
import os

image_file = "3_496.png"

ocr = PaddleOCR(use_gpu=True)
image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_file)
result = ocr.ocr(image_path, cls=True)

if None not in result:
    print(f"OCR result for {image_file}:")
    for line in result[0]:
        print(line[1][0])

Below is the image file:

In this image, Paddle OCR is able to extract almost all the items but failed in extracting 4 (PACK SIZE). I have some more very similar images and have noticed that it fails in extracting single digits. Is it true or may be I am doing something wrong?
Below is the output after running the above code:
OCR result for 3_496.png: PAGLNILE. PIGRWGIGHT 400g DATCHNUMHERE USLOYI 205257 31/07/2024 12.22. CUTIN NZ
